# How do I modify a binary file in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a command to modify a binary file in the shell?

First, I created a file with all 0xFF values:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1K count=1 | tr "\000" "\377" > ./Test.img
hexdump Test.img
```

Output:

```
0000000 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
*
0000400
```

Then I wanted to change some byte value like

```
0000000 aaaa ffff bbbb ffff cccc ffff ffff ffff
*
0000400
```

How can I change that? Or is there a command in shell script?

Comment: Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214820/patching-a-binary-with-dd

Comment: The [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) question is *"Patching a binary with dd"*

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Python

Python was designed to be binary-clean, so here is one approach:

```
python -c 'open("New.img", "wb").write( "\xaa\xaa\xff\xff\xbb\xbb\xff\xff\xcc\xcc" + open("Test.img", "rb").read()[10:] )'
```

We can use `hexdump` to view the resulting file:

```
hexdump New.img
```

Output:

```
0000000 aaaa ffff bbbb ffff cccc ffff ffff ffff
0000010 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
*
0000400
```

#### Using shell

The shell is **not** binary-clean.  For example, no shell string can contain the character `\x00`.  Consequently, any approach using shell may be subject to unpleasant surprises.  However, if one must, try:

```
LC_ALL=C; { printf "%s" $'\xaa\xaa\xff\xff\xbb\xbb\xff\xff\xcc\xcc'; tail -c+11 New.img; } >New2.img
```

Comment: Thanks,but i wanted to use shell not python

Comment: @CKvir OK.  Shell approach added but note that problems are inherent.

Comment: If i want to change second line or other line how can i do?
0000010 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff AAAA ffff
......
0000030 ffff ffff ffff ffff BBBB ffff ffff ffff

Comment: And also there have some problem ,either use python or shell the file size will change, i dont want file size change and other binary value still maintain 0xff, is that possible?

Comment: In my tests, there was no change in file size for either method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `vim -b bin-file-name`. This would start [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) in binary mode, which allows you to do anything to any file, as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: The question was about editing in a shell script.